# Fetch Details from 2 APIs and setState according to a dropdown - React Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, rest, get, axios, use-effect

I have a functional component named Calendar wherein each month is a Button. I have designed two APIs:

1. The first one fetches the data from the API when it is loaded for the first time, and nothing is selected from the dropdown.
   Below is the output, on Postman:

   ```
    [
    { 
        "month": 1,
        "count": 5
    },
    {
       "month": 3,
       "count": 2
    },
    {
        "month": 10,
        "count": 4
    },
    {
        "month": 11,
        "count": 3
    }
   ```

   ]`

Now I have the following states,

```
        const [jan, setJan] = useState(0);
        const [feb, setFeb] = useState(0);
        const [mar, setMar] = useState(0);
        const [apr, setApr] = useState(0);
        const [may, setMay] = useState(0);
        const [june, setJune] = useState(0);
        const [july, setJuly] = useState(0);
        const [aug, setAug] = useState(0);
        const [sept, setSept] = useState(0);
        const [oct, setOct] = useState(0);
        const [nov, setNov] = useState(0);
        const [dec, setDec] = useState(0);
        const [month, setMonth] = useState([]);
        const cleanup = () =>{
                 setJan(0);
                 setFeb(0);
                 setMar(0);
                 setApr(0);
                 setMay(0);
                 setJune(0);
                 setJuly(0);
                 setAug(0);
                 setSept(0);
                 setOct(0);
                 setNov(0);
                 setDec(0);
}
    const [month, setMonth] = useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
```

The state of each month should get changed according to the dropdown, if I select a student say Rani, her total score in each month should be displayed, if I select Ramu, his score should be displayed on the button.
Now, I have 2 different APIs for this, if no name is selected the default api fetches the information, if not, another api with studentname fetches information according to the student selected.

Suppose, I select Rani from the dropdown and according to the API's output given below:

```
[
    {
        "month": 11,
        "count": 1
    }
]
```

Only the November Month button should show count as 1, and rest of them 0.
If I don't select anything on the dropdown, the default API should work.
I have designed the below code it shows the number of notifications when it's loaded properly, but as soon as I change the name and again not select anything, for all the months it shows 0.
Below is the useEffect code for the same.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(name!=""){
        cleanup();
        axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/teacherportal/1234/${name}")
            .then(res => {
                setMonth(res.data)
                month.forEach(mon => {
                    {
                        (month.map(mon => {
                            if (mon["month"] === 1)
                                setJan(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 2)
                                setFeb(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 3)
                                setMar(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 4)
                                setApr(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 5)
                                setMay(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 6)
                                setJune(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 7)
                                setJuly(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 8)
                                setAug(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 9)
                                setSept(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] == 10)
                                setOct(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 11)
                                setNov(mon["count"]);
                            else if (mon["month"] === 12)
                                setDec(mon["count"]);

                        }
                        ))
                    }
                })
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
        }
    else{
       
     axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/teacherportal/1234")
        .then(res => {
            setMonth(res.data)
            month.forEach(mon => {
                {
                    (month.map(mon => {
                        if (mon["month"] === 1)
                            setJan(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 2)
                            setFeb(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 3)
                            setMar(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 4)
                            setApr(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 5)
                            setMay(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 6)
                            setJune(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 7)
                            setJuly(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 8)
                            setAug(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 9)
                            setSept(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] == 10)
                            setOct(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 11)
                            setNov(mon["count"]);
                        else if (mon["month"] === 12)
                            setDec(mon["count"]);

                    }
                    ))
                }
            })
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
    }
}, [month,name]);
```

Below is the dropdown onChange handler:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {

        setCustomer(event.target.value);
        if (event.target.value === "Rani") {
            setName("Rani");
        }
        else if (event.target.value === "Ramu") {
            setName("Ramu");
        }
        else if (event.target.value === "Lalu") {
            setName("Lalu");
        }
    }
```

If I choose the student from dropdown, and there was no data for some month for that student, the data fetched from the default api was overriding instead of showing 0, and hence the cleanup function.
Can someone please help with the same, Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are the `setMonth` and `month` variables in the same function. `setMonth` doesn't update the `month` variable directly, but does this in a next render call.

To solve your problem, bypass the `setMonth` after you receive the data in both calls:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8081/api/teacherportal/1234/${name}")
            .then(res => {
                res.data.forEach(mon => {
```

Although this code may work, it can be simplified a lot.

Storing your month data in a single `useState` makes it a lot easier to read and means no more mapping from month (number) to setState functions.

```
// array with 12 entries
const [months, setMonths] = useState(Array(12).fill(0));

// jan = months[0];
// feb = months[1];
// ...
```

In your `useEffect` hook, the code that handles the API response is identical. You can remove a lot of code (and use the single useState from above) to make it look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    if (name !== '') {
      return axios.get('http://localhost:8081/api/teacherportal/1234/${name}');
    }

    return axios.get('http://localhost:8081/api/teacherportal/1234');
  };

  getData()
    .then(({ data }) => {
      // start with empty months data (same as `cleanup()`)
      const monthsData = Array(12).fill(0);

      // populate the new array with your API data
      data.forEach(entry => {
        // the API returns the month starting from 1, while the array index starts from 0.
        monthsData[entry.month - 1] = entry.count;
      });

      setMonths(monthsData);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Failed to get data', error)
    });
}, [name]);
```

Lastly, the handleChange function can be simplified to this:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  setCustomer(event.target.value);
  setName(event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, this did reduce a lot of code and it worked! :)